# Can we use ASP.NET Core 2.2 Identity for Login page in Angular 7?

Tags: asp.net-core, angular7, asp.net-core-identity

I have been trying to implement Login logic using **Identity** from ASP.NET Core 2.2 and Angular 7. I have failed to find any working example using these.Microsoft uses MVC framework for identity example.I Have found tutorials for implementing Registering of new users using Identity with Angular 7, but with Login JWT token is being used.

Is it possible to use identity for login authentication in Angular 7 and ASP.NET Core 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible and it is fairly simple, but there are a few things to keep in mind:

First of all, Identity Framework is just a set of helper objects/methods for user management, so you are not limited to it and you can do everything on your own.

Secondly, there are two major approaches to user authentication:

- Cookie Based Authentication
- Token Based Authentication

If you understand them well, you can do whatever you want with them.

You can find a complete tutorial [here](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/07/18/secure-an-asp-net-core-web-api-using-cookies/) by Rui Figueiredo.

Comment: thanks for your comment.So does Identity uses cookie based authentication?Should I use JWT or Identity for Angular Login Auth.

Comment: @user11959345 It supports both. Cookies are much easier but there is no best approach, each one has it's own pros and cons. You can find their comparison on the net.